# Mercurial repositories hosting with different user access levels

Tags: hosting, mercurial

I want to set a few Mercurial 'central' repositories on one machine.

There are few things I need to have working though:

- Each repository should have its own ACL, with different users allowed to push/pull
- It shouldn't be ssh-based (it shouldn't require users to have shell accounts on that machine)
- So, I guess that leaves me with some `https` with basic authentication, right?

Are there any working solutions that provide this kind of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try Fog Creek [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/). Its not free, but nice. [Sharesource](http://sharesource.org) also offers this functionality, but no private repositories. Sharesource (itself) is open source, so you could conceivably install it on an intranet if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

These days, I would use [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) to do what you want. It is free and open source and gives you a Bitbucket-like view of the repositories.

You can configure push/pull permissions on a per-repository basis or on a user group basis. It even supports LDAP, which is very nice in big organizations.

Comment: RhodeCode is Python - it's not the easiest task to run in on ordinary box (imagine default Win-station, for example)

Answer (score 1):

[SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home) (requires Java 1.6 on server side):

> The easiest way to share and manage your Git, Mercurial and Subversion repositories over http.
>
> - Very easy installation
> - No need to hack configuration files, SCM-Manager is completely configureable from its Web-Interface
> - No Apache and no database installation is required
> - Central user, group and permission management
> - Out of the box support for Git, Mercurial and Subversion
> - Full RESTFul Web Service API (JSON and XML)
> - Rich User Interface
> - Simple Plugin API
> - Useful plugins available ( f.e. Ldap-, ActiveDirectory-, PAM-Authentication)
> - Licensed under the BSD-License

It allows separate permissions per repository (it has no way to set permissions for a group of repositories, yet), and doesn't require user accounts defined on the server.

Comment: It is worth noting existence of scm-branchwp-plugin and scm-pathwp-plugin, which allow more fine-grained ACLs - for (write) accessible repository some parts (branches or plain paths) can be write-protected

Comment: +1 for most lightweight solution, even if **it require Java on host**

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HgLab](http://hglabhq.com/): it's a hosted Mercurial server with pull and push support, access control and Active Directory integration.

Comment: Woah - one sure fire way to bring yourself to the attention of the systsem is to post the exact same answer to multiple questions - it makes you look like a spammer.

Comment: Actually - having read one of your earlier answers I do think you're borderline spamming now so be very careful about making identical posts and also telling people that this service is yours.

Comment: I can't see any mentions for ACLs deeper than Repository in HgLab

Comment: @Iain Sorry for that. You can delete these altogether.

Comment: @LazyBadger True, it's not mentioned, but HgLab supports "standard" Mercurial ACLs where you can specify branch and path-level permissions.

Comment: ACLs **are not standard in Mercurial** (at this level - doesn't enabled from a box), it's additional Extension

Comment: @LazyBadger That's why I quoted "standard" -- at least it's bundled with Mercurial. HgLab, however, requires no additional "extensions" or configuration to interpret those correctly.

Comment: @AntonGogolev: If I (or you) delete too much you may well end up being auto banned by the system so leave it as it is for now - lesson learned and all that.